# Data from Grails to MongoDB, where to check the data?

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I'm trying to connect grails to mongodb. These are the steps that I'm doing,

Added the line in `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
compile  ":mongodb:3.0.2" 
//commented hibernate plugin
```

And I have created a domain class like this:

```
package com.grailsinaction 

import org.bson.types.ObjectId 

class AuditEntry { 

    static mapWith = "mongo" 
    ObjectId id; 
    String message 

    static constraints = { 
    } 

    static mapping = { 
        collection "logs" 
        database "audit" 
        version false 
    } 
}
```

For this corresponding domain class, I have created a test class like this:

```
@TestFor(AuditEntry) 
class AuditEntrySpec extends Specification { 

    def setup() { 
    } 

    def cleanup() { 
    } 

    void "Testing mongo db connection"() { 
        def auditEntry = new AuditEntry(message: "Anto") 
        auditEntry.save(); 

        assert auditEntry.findAll().size() > 1 
    } 
}
```

When I run `grails test-app integration` its passing. And I can also able to see the logs like this:

2014-11-05T20:43:24.781+0530 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56972 #5 (2 connections now open) 
2014-11-05T20:43:29.151+0530 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:56972 (1 connection now open)

in my `mongod` process.

But I'm not sure, where the data is going! I have given in my mapping like database name should be `audit` and collection name is `logs`.

So I tried the following commands on mongo console:

```
use audit 
show collections
```

This returns empty. I'm confused here, not sure where the data itself going.

Where I'm making the mistake? Or I have missed in the step?

Comment: Did you try running "show dbs" to see what other databases are present?

Comment: If my memory serves me correct, testing doesn't persist data.  If you want a good mongo client, try Robomongo

Comment: @getbuckts: Ya what you have said is correct!